# (Fixed) Fictional calendar is 345 days with 28 hours per day and 14 hours day and night cycle--how old are 13 year olds vs Earth calendar?

Tags: planets, mathematics

I had the worst brain fart earlier, sorry.

My fictional calendar is currently 345 days with 28 hours per day, with 14 hours day and night cycle [I have no idea why I effed that up so badly prior]. I just want to ask--if my characters are 13 in their world with this calendar, how old would they be on Earth?

Edit: I'm basically figuring out how I want their actual calendar to look (e.g. ours is 12 months for 365 days and 24 hours) but just asked this so I wouldn't be making additional stupid mistakes.

Comment: I expect this will still be closed. It's just a math problem. Assuming an hour on your planet is equal to an hour on Earth, multiply your planet's hours in a day by the planet's days in a year and by the age of your character, then divide by the hours in Earth's day and the days in Earth's year. I sincerely apologize for asking, but how old are you? Because this is 7th grade math.

Comment: I'm doing the math but fear making stupid mistakes! ^^" Thanks; it's fine if it's closed.

Answer (score 2):

**In the spirit of teaching a person to fish...**

Comparing two related values is most easily done by reducing everything to the largest common unit of measure. In your case, the largest common unit of measure is hours.

***Assumption:** The hours on your fictional world are identical to the hours on Earth. However, even if this weren't true, there's always a largest common unit of measure. Even if you say that the "second" on your planet is 1.066 of a terrestrial second, it's just a matter of reducing everything to seconds and applying the 1.066 multiplier at the right time.*

***Assumption:** We are not dealing with relativistic effects of any kind. If the gravity on your planet isn't exactly the gravity on Earth, the comparison becomes more difficult. Not impossible, just more complicated. Frankly, if someone lived their entire life at the altitude of Mt. Everest and their age compared to that of someone who lived their entire life at sea level, there would be a difference in their ages even though the number of planetary rotations and orbits are identical. Relativistic time is gooey and best understood with a couple of aspirin.*

***Assumption:** We are completely ignoring leap years, which occur every four years and we would need to know exactly when your character was born compared to Earth's calendar to be that precise. We're also going to ignore the periodic changes to Earth's calendar due to the Atomic Clock and the fact that Earth's day length is ever-so-slowly changing. (You might have noticed occasionally that an extra second or so is added to the end of a year. My father likes to go out on the porch and whistle during that time so he can claim that he whistled on December 32nd.)*

Also, note that the day/night cycle isn't actually important to the question. If a difference exists in the ratio of day/night cycle on your planet and Earth, it won't change the answer.

So, we first need to reduce the age of your character to hours.

On your planet:

- One year is 345 days.
- One day is 28 hours.
- Your character has lived 13 years.
- Your character is 13 * 345 * 28 = 125,580 hours old.

On Earth, we have:

- One year is 365 days.
- One day is 24 hours.
- So, one year is 8,760 hours.

The comparison is easy. Divide the number of hours in Earth's year into the age of your character in hours. The result is the number of Earth years your character has lived.

125,580 / 8,760 = 14.3356 Earth years

And, for fun, 0.3356 year is 122.49 days or about 4 months.

*Exactly how many months +/- days depends on exactly what day your character was born on Earth's calendar. As fate would have it, your numerical choices landed a result right at the 4-month mark, which means the Earth date they were born on matters when calculating exactly how many months past 14 years they've lived. Cheers.*

**If you still do not understand how to calculate that number for yourself, my answer failed.**

Also, for future reference, yours is technically not a worldbuilding question. It would have been fine to ask it in [The Factory Floor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor) chat room where you can ask any question you want. (Be patient if you do this, the Floor isn't manned 24/7.) But here on Main, questions are expected to follow the rules found in the Tour and the Help Center. I'm using your first question to help you understand that there are limits to what belongs here. Thanks.

Comment: In answering this query, you've put me in a bit of a pickle! Obviously this is a kind of "homework question", arithmetic in specific, and I concur that it was rightly closed on that basis. Yet you have in fact provided a useful worldbuilding response. In light of the question's closure, its negative votes and the now impending deletion vote, I'd hate to see your answer disappear. I'm wondering if you've put any thought into a way of preserving it, simply because you went above and beyond the mere arithmetical statement that provided the right answer. (cont)

Comment: (cont) -- My first reaction to the question was to follow suit with deletion --- nothing personal against you rikurins! --- but stayed my sufferaging mouse click finger in order to resolve the quandry of what to do when a really excellent answer is provided for a question that is inappropriate for this forum or is just really bad. My first thought was to perhaps see if this question could be improved; or barring that, could a new question be asked that might also result in the same answer.

Comment: @elemtilas  hand slap accepted. To be honest, my only purpose was to give the user the chance to see what value the site has and an introduction to how the site works. I expected the closure, although I'm surprised by the delete vote. It's fairly rare for deletes outside of Mod deletions to happen here. Nevertheless, I'm not convinced of how universally useful the answer is. My feelings won't be hurt if the answer vanishes. But I am disappointed that the OP hasn't been more engaged.

Comment: Well, the answer is NOT useful because of the maths! It's useful because of your exposition of *worldbuilding process*, in specific, the introduction of concepts such as relativistic effects, leap years / calendric systems & measure of time, comparative units of time measurement and the like as matters for consideration.  There is also a kind of "culture shock" that every worldbuilder faces at some point. Where we face the idea that a world doesn't have to be exactly equivalent to the real world and that when they differ, there are loads of butterflies we must account for!